# Draw ellipse passing through 3 points

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, gdi+, gdi

I have next task - draw ellipe trough 3 points (like in the picture).
[image: ellipse]
.
User can drag theese points that to change ellipse size. Two of points placed on edges of great axis. In my solution I use GDI throug Graphics class.
Now my solution is calculate rectangle corresponding to an ellipse and use 
DrawEllipse method and rotate transform (if it's need). But this solution has many mathematical calculation. Maybe there is the simplest approach to solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use the `DrawEllipse` method from a rotation, the minor axis and two vertices.

First we calculate the `Size` of the bounding `Rectangle`:

Given the `Points A and B` sitting on the short sides of length `smallSize` we get the long side with a little Pythagoras:

```
int longSide = (int)(Math.Sqrt((A.Y - B.Y) * (A.Y - B.Y) + (B.X - A.X) * (B.X - A.X)));
```

So :

```
Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(longSide, smallSize);
```

Next we need the rotation angle:

```
float angle = -(float)(Math.Atan2(A.Y - B.Y, B.X - A.X) * 180f / Math.PI);
```

And it will make things easier to also get the center `Point C`:

```
Point C = new Point((A.X + B.X)/ 2, (A.Y + B.Y)/ 2);
```

The last thing we want is a routine that draws an ellipse of a given `Size`, rotated around `C` at an angle:

```
void DrawEllipse(Graphics G, Pen pen, Point center, Size size, float angle)
{
    int h2 = size.Height / 2;
    int w2 = size.Width / 2;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( new Point(center.X - w2, center.Y - h2), size );

    G.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
    G.RotateTransform(angle);
    G.TranslateTransform(-center.X, -center.Y);
    G.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
    G.ResetTransform();
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is a little testbed that brings it all together:

```
Point A = new Point(200, 200); // *
Point B = new Point(500, 250);
int smallSize = 50;


void doTheDraw(PictureBox pb)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);

    float angle = -(float)(Math.Atan2(A.Y - B.Y, B.X - A.X) * 180f / Math.PI);
    int longSide = (int)(Math.Sqrt((A.Y - B.Y) * (A.Y - B.Y) + (B.X - A.X) * (B.X - A.X)));
    Point C = new Point((A.X + B.X) / 2, (A.Y + B.Y) / 2);
    Size size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)longSide, smallSize);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Orange, 3f))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // a nice background grid (optional):
        DrawGrid(g, 0, 0, 100, 50, 10,
            Color.LightSlateGray, Color.DarkGray, Color.Gainsboro);

        // show the points we use (optional):
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, A.X - 4, A.Y - 4, 8, 8);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, B.X - 3, B.Y - 3, 7, 7);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, C.X - 5, C.Y - 5, 11, 11);

        // show the connection line (optional):
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Orange, A, B);

        // here comes the ellipse:
        DrawEllipse(g, pen, C, size, angle);
    }
    pb.Image = bmp;
}
```

The grid is a nice helper:

```
void DrawGrid(Graphics G, int ox, int oy, 
              int major, int medium, int minor, Color c1, Color c2, Color c3)
{
    using (Pen pen1 = new Pen(c1, 1f))
    using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(c2, 1f))
    using (Pen pen3 = new Pen(c3, 1f))
    {
        pen2.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
        pen3.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
        for (int x = ox; x < G.VisibleClipBounds.Width; x += major)
            G.DrawLine(pen1, x, 0, x, G.VisibleClipBounds.Height);
        for (int y = oy; y < G.VisibleClipBounds.Height; y += major)
            G.DrawLine(pen1, 0, y, G.VisibleClipBounds.Width, y);

        for (int x = ox; x < G.VisibleClipBounds.Width; x += medium)
            G.DrawLine(pen2, x, 0, x, G.VisibleClipBounds.Height);
        for (int y = oy; y < G.VisibleClipBounds.Height; y += medium)
            G.DrawLine(pen2, 0, y, G.VisibleClipBounds.Width, y); 

        for (int x = ox; x < G.VisibleClipBounds.Width; x += minor)
            G.DrawLine(pen3, x, 0, x, G.VisibleClipBounds.Height);
        for (int y = oy; y < G.VisibleClipBounds.Height; y += minor)
            G.DrawLine(pen3, 0, y, G.VisibleClipBounds.Width, y);
    }
}
```

Note that I made  `A, B, smallSide` class level variables so I can modify them during my tests, (and I did `*`)..

As you can see I have added a `TrackBar` to make the `smallside` dynamic; for even more fun I have added this `MouseClick` event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) A = e.Location;
    else B = e.Location;
    doTheDraw(pictureBox1);
}
```

I hope some of my logic can help you out on what you're trying to achieve. Next question you make try to add more info and be less generic.

Comment: Thank you! Some things is not fully clear for me now, but I think I can get troug it. Now I have to calculate only small size, and it's much better than my first idea.

Comment: I found one misteke. Angle should be without minus sign to correct drawing. Also need add condition for available coordinates for points.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the similarity transform (translation and rotation) that brings the first two points to `(-a, 0)` and `(a, 0)`. [This can be done with a matrix transform or complex numbers.]

Apply the same transform to the third point. Now the equation of the reduced ellipse is

```
x² / a² + y² / b² = 1.
```

You simply determine the parameter `b` by plugging the reduced coordinates of the third point,

```
b = y / √(1 - x²/a²).
```

Now you have

- the center,
- the orientation of the axis,
- the length of the major axis,
- the length of the minor axis.